# How to programmatically build a path for a module in the cache using ivy api?

Tags: java, dependencies, ivy

I would like to perform a **build path from the cache** as described in the [ivy official documentation](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/principle.html) programmatically (ie not using ant or the command line tool).

[image]

Unfortunately, there is no pointer to the corresponding classes in the ivy API that could help achieve that.

**Is there any code sample that I could learn from?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A starting point would be the read from the [Main.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.ivy/ivy/2.4.0/org/apache/ivy/Main.java#Main.%3Cinit%3E%28%29) from ivy itself and look how **[cachepath](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/cachepath.html)** operation is [performed](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.ivy/ivy/2.4.0/org/apache/ivy/Main.java#Main.outputCachePath%28org.apache.ivy.Ivy%2Cjava.io.File%2Corg.apache.ivy.core.module.descriptor.ModuleDescriptor%2Cjava.lang.String[]%2Cjava.lang.String%29) in Ivy's code.

Too see a sample of the output, run

```
java -jar ivy-2.4.0.jar -dependency commons-logging commons-logging 1.1 -cachepath file.txt
```

The file `file.txt` holds:

```
/home/cran/.ivy2/cache/commons-logging/commons-logging/sources/commons-logging-1.1-sources.jar:/home/cran/.ivy2/cache/commons-logging/commons-logging/j
ars/commons-logging-1.1.jar:/home/cran/.ivy2/cache/log4j/log4j/jars/log4j-1.2.12.jar:/home/cran/.ivy2/cache/logkit/logkit/jars/logkit-1.0.1.jar:/home/c
ran/.ivy2/cache/avalon-framework/avalon-framework/jars/avalon-framework-4.1.3.jar:/home/cran/.ivy2/cache/javax.servlet/servlet-api/jars/servlet-api-2.3
.jar
```